# Android Transition Element Flicker

Tags: android, transition

I'm having an issue where shared element (between activities) is flickering when the back button is pressed.

Please see the following 10 second video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-z9yj0xGNkY

If you look closely, the bottom half of the logo will clip and come back on the frame. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Edit:

Here's the transitions that I set (independent of the shared element):

```
private void setTransitions() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        Explode enterTransition = new Explode();

        enterTransition.setDuration(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.anim_duration_long));
        enterTransition.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
        enterTransition.excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, true);

        getWindow().setEnterTransition(enterTransition);

        Fade exitTransition = new Fade();

        exitTransition.setDuration(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.anim_duration_long));

        getWindow().setExitTransition(exitTransition);

    }
}
```

Here is the shared element transition (1st activity):

```
i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LoginActivity.class);
View sharedView = findViewById(R.id.logo);
String transitionName = getString(R.string.logo_transition);

ActivityOptionsCompat transitionActivityOptions = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(SplashScreenActivity.this, sharedView, transitionName);

startActivityForResult(i,RESULT_CODE,transitionActivityOptions.toBundle());
```

I don't do anything in the second activity, as when back is pressed, Android automatically reverses the transition.

**Edit: After removing the excludeTarget, the flashing isn't there. However, the status bar & navigation bar now flash.**

Comment: some code? is this an activity transition? what exactly are you doing?

Comment: @muetzenflo I added the transition code that is used to start the activity.